# How do you add a chandelier to a ceiling fan?

Tags: wiring

I found a gorgeous chandelier that I want to replace the light fixture on my fan with.  How do I do this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's no way we can answer this without a lot more info (e.g. pictures of the chandelier and existing fan light), and perhaps not even then. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post photos of all parts involved?

Comment: Seems to me that a chandelier below a ceiling fan == a dust collector.

Comment: When we have added a light fixture to a fan we have always bought one designed for mounting and connection to that fan. Possibly one could adapt a fixture meant to be mounted on a wall box, but this would have to be evaluated on a case by case basis. In general, I would say this is going to give rise to problems. Even if you got it mounted and connected, a chandelier would probably go into resonant oscillations when the fan was on.

Comment: So... it would wiggle? :D

Comment: Yes, a complex structure like a chandelier will have several resonance frequencies.  If the fan, at one of those speeds, hits one of those resonance frequencies, the thing will tear itself apart.

Comment: I have seen light fixtures for fans called chandelier they usually have 3-4 lamps. I have to agree with Jim that the fan has to be designed to allow the addition of lighting. If the wiring comes down to allow the addition of a fixture it is usually best to purchase the fixture from the same manufacturer or a fixture that lists your model of fan being compatible because not all light fixtures fit all fans.